# A method not working in Vue.js and can't figure out what the problem is

Tags: vue.js

From the code below, I'm sending email using EmailJs library and the alert method get's executed after submitting but the change method doesn't. What I'm I missing?

Error message on the console is

```
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined
        at app.js:2755
```

My Script

```
<script>
    import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          flash: false,
        };
      },
    
      methods: {
        sendEmail: (e) => {
          emailjs
            .sendForm(
              "service_k9mhh",
              "template_epghgfh",
              e.target,
              "user_w9U76tg77yhcggh"
            )
            .then(
              (result) => {
                console.log("SUCCESS!", result.status, result.text);
                alert("Message Sent Successfully")
                this.change();
                
              },
    
              (error) => {
                console.log("FAILED...", error);
              }
            );
        // Reset form field
         
        },
        change(){
          this.flash = true;
        }
       
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Without arrow functions as shown below, It still throws the same error.

```
  methods: {
    sendEmail: function (e) {
      emailjs
        .sendForm(
          "service_",
          "template_",
          e.target,
          "user_"
        )
        .then(
          function (result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS!", result.status, result.text);
            this.change();
          },

          function (error) {
            console.log("FAILED...", error);
          }
        );
      
    },
    change: function () {
      this.flash = true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message you are getting ?

Comment: @Maylor I've edited the question and provided the error.

Comment: Try `sendEmail (e) {...}`

Comment: The error is still the same

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in arrow functions `this` does not refer to the Vue instance so `this.change` is not defined there.

Read this:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: I've changed all the arrow function to anonymous functions but I still get the same error!

Comment: Declare your function the same way as you did with your change method.

Comment: I did just that. Check in the question I've added the code how I've adjusted from arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you and eldo were both half right. You need to use a regular function syntax when declaring a method, and an arrow function in any nested .then's.
Using an arrow function in your then and catch handler's ensures that 'this' remains a reference to the Vue instance.

Your method wants to look like this:

```
sendEmail(e) {
  emailjs
    .sendForm("service_", "template_", e.target, "user_")
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("SUCCESS!", result.status, result.text);
      this.change();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("FAILED...", error);
    });
},
```